# on scroll swapping classes on a menu - IE issue

Tags: javascript, css, function

HI guys the code below works perfectly fine on firefox and the class "header  is-sticky" is loaded with css on scroll. however in IE the function does not work at all. Pls assist on an IE fix for on scroll

function swapMenu(){

```
if($(document).scrollTop() > 102 )
{

   var yy = document.getElementsByClassName("header")[0];
   yy.className = "header is-sticky";
}

else
  {

   var zz = document.getElementsByClassName("header is-sticky")[0];
   zz.className = "header";
   }

}</script> 

<body class="debug" onscroll="swapMenu();">


 <div id="header" class="header"> </div>


</body>
```

Comment: So where is the CSS for `header` and `is-sticky`? BTW, that's two classes, not one.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the onscroll from your body tag, and try adding then following

```
window.onscroll = swapMenu;
```

to your javascript, outside of the function.